# Query string in drupal service custom resources

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-services

I am trying to use query string structure in drupal services API. it's not working for me. 
I have also search most of the solutions, but all failed.
here is m drupal code:

```
function rapid_services_resources() {
  $resources = array(
    'get_data' => array(
      'operations' => array(
        'retrieve' => array(
          'help' => t('Gets user email of uid passed.'),
          'callback' => 'my_module_get_user_email',
          'args' => array(
                 array(
                'name' => 'nid',
                'type' => 'int',
                'description' => 'The display ID of the view to get.',
                'source' => array('param' => 'nid'),
                'optional' => TRUE,
                'default value' => 'default',
              ),
          ),
          'access arguments' => '_blog_access_provide_access',
          'access callback' => '_blog_access_provide_access',
          //~ 'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $resources;
}

function _blog_access_provide_access() {
  return TRUE;
}

function my_module_get_user_email($nid){
    var_dump($args);die;
}
```

I want url like this.:

```
http://localhost/drupaltest/rapidapi/get_data/?nid=111
```

Please let me know where i did wrong.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here are to reference that will be useful

http://pingv.com/blog/an-introduction-drupal-7-restful-services

https://www.drupal.org/node/783460

Also I am not sure about the query string, but for the retrieve operation you can set it as part of the url 
ex:

```
http://localhost/drupaltest/rapidapi/get_data/<nid should be here>
http://localhost/drupaltest/rapidapi/get_data/111
```

Also using the source path as source

```
'source' => array('path' => '0'),
```

I would think that source `param` only works for an `index` operation and not retrieve